# Remove pilcrow from SQL Worksheet

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this annoying pilcrow that shows on every line of my Worksheet : 
[image]

Does somebody know the shortcut to get rid of it ? thanks.

Comment: Found it ! Ctrl + shift+ W. And yes it's a duplicate..but i've spent 30 minutes searching and didn't come across that question :)

Comment: This question is now the first search result for "pilcrow sql developer" so it should be a bit easier for the next person who knows the character's name *8-)